# React-Admin Permissions with resource

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a problem with the permissions of resources with React Admin.
I want to hide some resources with a particular role of user, using an array of roles coming inside the JWT obtained with the login.

This is the authProvider for the authentication

```js
import decodeJwt from 'jwt-decode';

export default {

    login: ({ username, password }) => {

        const request = new Request('http://myresource.org', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        });
        return fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(({ token }) => {
                const decodedToken = decodeJwt(token);
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                localStorage.setItem('permissions', JSON.stringify(decodedToken.roles));
             });
    },


    logout: () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        localStorage.removeItem('permissions');
        return Promise.resolve();
    },


    checkError: error => {

    },


    checkAuth: () => {
        return localStorage.getItem('token') ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();
    },


    getPermissions: () => {
        const roles = localStorage.getItem('permissions');
        console.log(roles);    //This print correctly the array
        return roles ? Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(roles)) : Promise.reject();
    }
};
```

and this is the main app

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Admin, Resource, resolveBrowserLocale } from 'react-admin';

import Dashboard from './Dashboard';

/*** Import Lingue ***/ 
import polyglotI18nProvider from 'ra-i18n-polyglot';
import englishMessages from 'ra-language-english';
import italianMessages from 'ra-language-italian';
import * as resources_IT from './translations/Resources_IT';

/*** Import Grafici ***/ 
import UserIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Group';
import HotelIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Hotel';
import BookingIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MenuBook';
import DeviceIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DeviceHub';
import CustomerIcon from '@material-ui/icons/EmojiPeople';
import DeviceAccountIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountBox';

/*** Import Providers ***/ 
import dataProvider from './providers/DataProvider';
import authProvider from './providers/AuthProvider';

/*** Import Resources ***/ 
import { HotelList, HotelEdit, HotelCreate } from './resources/Hotel';
import { DeviceList, DeviceEdit, DeviceCreate } from './resources/Device';
import { UserList, UserEdit, UserCreate, UserShow } from './resources/User';
import { BookingList, BookingEdit, BookingCreate } from './resources/Booking';
import { CustomerList, CustomerEdit, CustomerCreate } from './resources/Customer';
import { DeviceAccountList, DeviceAccountEdit, DeviceAccountCreate } from './resources/DeviceAccount';



/* Configurazione della lingua del Browser */
const messages = {
    it: { ...italianMessages, ...resources_IT },
    en: englishMessages,
};

const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(
    locale => messages[locale] ? messages[locale] : messages.en, resolveBrowserLocale()
);


const App = () => (

    <Admin dashboard={Dashboard} dataProvider={dataProvider} i18nProvider={i18nProvider} authProvider={authProvider}>

        {permissions => [
        permissions.indexOf('SYSADM') >= 0 ? (<Resource name="hotels" list={HotelList} edit={HotelEdit} create={HotelCreate} icon={HotelIcon} />) : null,
        ]}

        <Resource name="roles" />
        <Resource name="users" list={UserList} edit={UserEdit} create={UserCreate} icon={UserIcon} />
        <Resource name="devices" list={DeviceList} edit={DeviceEdit} create={DeviceCreate} icon={DeviceIcon} />
        <Resource name="bookings" list={BookingList} edit={BookingEdit} create={BookingCreate} icon={BookingIcon} />
        <Resource name="customers" list={CustomerList} edit={CustomerEdit} create={CustomerCreate} icon={CustomerIcon} />
        <Resource name="deviceaccounts" list={DeviceAccountList} edit={DeviceAccountEdit} create={DeviceAccountCreate} icon={DeviceAccountIcon} />

    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

finally, this is the JWT:

```json
{
  "aud": "backoffice-fe",
  "sub": "email@test.com",
  "idHotels": [
    "21816730-a4ef-4fea-8fb9-adc019d80485"
  ],
  "roles": [
    "SYSADM"
  ],
  "iss": "backoffice-api"
}
```

Seems the `permissions` in app.js is not correctly obtained.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation's example:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Permissions.html#restricting-access-to-resources-or-views

Works for me. Just make sure to:

```
  const { loading, permissions } = usePermissions();
```

And then

```
 return loading
    ? (<div>Waiting for permissions...</div>)
    : (
      <>
        (your admin...)
```

Finally like in the doc:

```
{permissions => [
    // Restrict access to the edit and remove views to admin only
    <Resource
        name="customers"
        list={VisitorList}
        edit={permissions === 'admin' ? VisitorEdit : null}
        icon={VisitorIcon}
    />,
    // Only include the categories resource for admin users
    permissions === 'admin'
        ? <Resource name="categories" list={CategoryList} edit={CategoryEdit} icon={CategoryIcon} />
        : null,
]}
```

ps: To do so, you must use a function as the  only child.

Comment: here is the working link https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Permissions.html#restricting-access-to-resources-or-views

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to add more than one child enclose them in <></>

```
{permissions => [
    // Restrict access to the edit and remove views to admin only
    <Resource
        name="customers"
        list={VisitorList}
        edit={permissions === 'admin' ? VisitorEdit : null}
        icon={VisitorIcon}
    />,
    // Only include the categories resource for admin users
    permissions === 'admin'
        ? <>
          <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} edit={PostEdit} icon={PostIcon} />
          <Resource name="categories" list={CategoryList} edit={CategoryEdit} icon={CategoryIcon} />
          </>
        : null,
]}
```