# Show or Hide Resource based on Permission in React Admin Not working

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Show or Hide Resource based on Permission in React Admin Not working.

Trying to render a resource based on permissions.

Here is my solution

```
const App = () => {

const { loading, permissions } = usePermissions(); 

return(
  <BrowserRouter>
    loading
    ? (<div>Waiting for permissions...</div>)
    : (
      <Admin  
            catchAll={NotFound} 
            dataProvider={dataProvider} 
            authProvider={authProvider} 
            loginPage={MyLoginPage} 
            >
            Permissions : {permissions} // Value: MEMBER, but the equality check fails.
            {permissions => [

            permissions === 'MEMBER' 
            ? <Resource name="address" options={{ label: 'Address' }} list={AddressList} edit={AddressEdit} create={AddressCreate} icon={GiPostStamp}/> 
            : null, 

           
            permissions === 'MEMBER' 
            ?  <Resource name="posts" options={{ label: 'Posts !' }}
            list={PostsSearchList} icon={GiPostStamp}/> 
            : null
            ]}

       </Admin>
  </BrowserRouter>)
};

export default App;
```

I am running into similar problem and built the similar solution but still equality check fails, in spite of the value === 'MEMBER'

I am really puzzled on why its happening ?

1. [React Admin render resources based on permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69772915/react-admin-render-resources-based-on-permissions)
2. [React-Admin Permissions with resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132803/react-admin-permissions-with-resource)
3. [React-Admin Permissions with resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132803/react-admin-permissions-with-resource)

Comment: As pointed in the second link that you posted, the "function as child" for permissions only works if Admin has only one child. In your example, it has two.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment, Now after changing it to just one child its working. But I am curious to know the rational behind it. If I am the dev, I would have certainly kept unlimited child to have that feature. I would suggest in the next version it can be seen.

Comment: We didn't design this limitation. We just added the permissions feature, thinking that people would either have components as child, or a function. We didn't think that people would have both.

Answer (score 1):

```
const App = () => {

const { loading, permissions } = usePermissions(); 

return(
  <BrowserRouter>
    loading
    ? (<div>Waiting for permissions...</div>)
    : (
      <Admin  
            catchAll={NotFound} 
            dataProvider={dataProvider} 
            authProvider={authProvider} 
            loginPage={MyLoginPage} 
            >
            {permissions => [

            permissions === 'MEMBER' 
            ? <>
             <Resource name="address" options={{ label: 'Address' }} list={AddressList} edit={AddressEdit} create={AddressCreate} icon={GiPostStamp}/>
             <Resource name="posts" options={{ label: 'Posts !' }}
            list={PostsSearchList} icon={GiPostStamp}/> 
             </>
            : null, 

          ]}

       </Admin>
  </BrowserRouter>)
};

export default App;
```

The problem was it allows only one child inside the condition.
This way you can include more than one child inside the condition.

Answer (score 1):

In [newer version](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Authorization.html) you can use the following syntax after you included `authProvider`, there is no need to `usePermissions` hook:

```
<Admin
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
    authProvider={authProvider}
>
    {permissions => [
        // Restrict access to the edit and remove views to admin only
        <Resource
            name="customers"
            list={VisitorList}
            edit={permissions === 'admin' ? VisitorEdit : null}
            icon={VisitorIcon}
        />,
        // Only include the categories resource for admin users
        permissions === 'admin'
            ? <Resource name="categories" list={CategoryList} edit={CategoryEdit} icon={CategoryIcon} />
            : null,
    ]}
</Admin>
```